# Select date from table with new column as result from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server 2008, how can I retrieve data from table1 with new magic column (bit value), this new column take 'true' if current id from table1 exist in table2, else take 'false'.

For example :

Table1

```
id  |  name
-----------
10  |  USA
11  |  UK
12  |  France
```

table2

```
id |  title  | fk
----------------------
1  |  v1     | 10
2  |  v2     | 10
3  |  v3     | 11
```

result :

```
id  |  name   | new column
----------------------------
10  |  USA    | true
11  |  UK     | true
12  |  France | false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.id,  table1.name, 
       CASE WHEN  table2.id IS NULL THEN 'False' ELSE 'True' END AS mycolumn
FROM table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.fk
```

Comment: Please provide a little explanation with your query.

Answer (score 0):

Read about different join types. this is basic SQL.

```
SELECT Table1.[id], [name], CASE WHEN Table2.[id] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END As [New column]
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN
Table2 ON(Table1.[id] = Table2.[fk])
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query returns the expected result:

```
SELECT T1.*
    ,CAST(CASE
            WHEN T2.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1
            ELSE 0
         END AS BIT) AS magic_column
FROM table1 T1
LEFT JOIN table2 T2 ON T1.id = T2.fk
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **left join** to get the data you want.

**SQL**

```
select A.*
,case when B.fk is not null then 'true' else 'false' end as [new column]
from table1 A
left join 
(
    select distinct fk from table2
)B on A.id=B.fk
```

**OUTPUT**

```
id  name    new column
10  USA     true
11  UK      true
12  France  false
```